# type 'IconData' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

Walking through the tutorial of "Adding interactivity to your Flutter App" I kept running to this error message:

type 'IconData' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Due to my inexperience I am not sure what the remedy is. Being this was a tutorial I found the answer code and copy pasted it into Visual Studio just to see how it was suppose to look. I received the same error. I did some looking through stack overflow and github. The examples I were finding had specifically called for IconData in the trouble code. In the tutorial code it only calls for IconData once and it it is a completely different widgets.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget titleSection = Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            /*1*/
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                /*2*/
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                  child: Text(
                    'Oeschinen Lake Campground',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Kandersteg, Switzerland',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey[500],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          FavoriteWidget(),
        ],
      ),
    );

    Color color = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;

    Widget buttonSection = Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          _buildButtonColumn(color, Icons.call, 'CALL'),
          _buildButtonColumn(color, Icons.near_me, 'ROUTE'),
          _buildButtonColumn(color, Icons.share, 'SHARE'),
        ],
      ),
    );

    Widget textSection = Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
      child: Text(
        'Lake Oeschinen lies at the foot of the Blüemlisalp in the Bernese '
            'Alps. Situated 1,578 meters above sea level, it is one of the '
            'larger Alpine Lakes. A gondola ride from Kandersteg, followed by a '
            'half-hour walk through pastures and pine forest, leads you to the '
            'lake, which warms to 20 degrees Celsius in the summer. Activities '
            'enjoyed here include rowing, and riding the summer toboggan run.',
        softWrap: true,
      ),
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter layout demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter layout demo'),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              'images/lake.jpg',
              width: 600,
              height: 240,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            titleSection,
            buttonSection,
            textSection,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Column _buildButtonColumn(Color color, IconData icon, String label) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Icon(icon, color: color),
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
          child: Text(
            label,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              color: color,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

// #docregion FavoriteWidget
class FavoriteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FavoriteWidgetState createState() => _FavoriteWidgetState();
}
// #enddocregion FavoriteWidget

// #docregion _FavoriteWidgetState, _FavoriteWidgetState-fields, _FavoriteWidgetState-build
class _FavoriteWidgetState extends State<FavoriteWidget> {
  // #enddocregion _FavoriteWidgetState-build
  bool _isFavorited = true;
  int _favoriteCount = 41;
  // #enddocregion _FavoriteWidgetState-fields

  // #docregion _toggleFavorite
  void _toggleFavorite() {
    setState(() {
      if (_isFavorited) {
        _favoriteCount -= 1;
        _isFavorited = false;
      } else {
        _favoriteCount += 1;
        _isFavorited = true;
      }
    });
  }
  // #enddocregion _toggleFavorite

  // #docregion _FavoriteWidgetState-build
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          child: IconButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            icon: (_isFavorited ? Icon(Icons.star) : Icon(Icons.star_border)),
            color: Colors.red[500],
            onPressed: _toggleFavorite,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 18,
          child: Container(
            child: Text('$_favoriteCount'),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
  // #docregion _FavoriteWidgetState-fields
}
```

The error was also specifically referencing line 34 : 11 which is the line FavoriteWidget().

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

The code you post works fine to me.

[image]

just be sure to add the correct image asset (images/lake.jpg) for example :
[image]

Be sure to set uses-material-design: true in pubspec.yaml for the icons to be included in the app.

And also try to update flutter and run flutter doctor to see if you have any other problem

Comment: Thank you for commenting. You are correct. I am using Visual Studio Code and I think sometimes hot reload does not clear everything previously. When I came back after work and ran the program it worked.